# Avoid neighbor fragment creation in Actiobar nav mode Tabs or Strips?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-actionbar

I'm using actionbar navigation mode Tabs and I'm having 3 tabs using async tasks that loads stuff from the internet.
When launching the activity the fragments next to the current one are created thus launching their own async task.

Is there any way to provente neighbor fragments creation?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a `ViewPager` for those tabs, in which case the behavior is normal. You could start the `AsyncTask` in the `onPageSelected()` callback of the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Yes I'm using it. I have onTabSelected() is it ok?